# Name resolution and DNS registration for a CentOS 7 Azure VM

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, azure, dhcp, centos7

I have a Linux VM (CentOS 7.2) running on Azure, which is configured as a DHCP client because this is required by the Azure platform; Azure DHCP correctly supplies a network configuration to the VM, including IP/subnet/gateway and the DNS servers to use, which are two Windows domain controllers also running on Azure VMs; Azure DHCP doesn't supply a DNS suffix, or to be exact it supplies a default one (`reddog.microsoft.com`) which is not correct for my environment and needs to be overriden.

The machine hostname is `testlinux`; the DNS suffix it must use is `drlab.local`; the IP address for the VM and the DNS servers to use are provided by Azure DHCP; there is a DNS zone in the DNS servers named `drlab.local`, which is configured to allow both secure and nonsecure dynamic updates.

I need to configure the following settings on the Linux VM:

- Use `drlab.local` as the DNS suffix in the machine hostname (by default the machine is configured only with a short name, not a FQDN).
- Use `drlab.local` as the default DNS suffix for name resolution.

I also need to automate the following actions:

- Add an entry to the `hosts` file mapping the IP address assigned by DHCP to the machine hostname (I have applications which require this entry to be present).
- Register the VM hostname and IP address in the Windows DNS service.

I also need the machine to correctly perform all of the above when its IP address changes (the context is a disaster recovery solution where a VM can be moved from one network to a different one).

I found various docs, posts and links about all of the above issues, but many of them are wrong / don't apply / don't work on Azure / don't work on CentOS 7.

Can someone please help me gather together all the required steps to have an Azure Linux CentOS 7 VM correctly configure its name resolution and register its name in the Windows DNS service?

---

Note: I'm only mentioning Azure for the sake of completeness, and to clarify that I need the VM to be a DHCP client and I don't have any control on the DHCP service; the question actually boils down to "I have a CentOS 7 system configured as a DHCP client, I need it to correctly handle name resolution and register itself in a Windows DNS service".

Comment: Can you setup MAC address reservations on the DHCP server side and then just setup a host A records for that IP? It'd still get the IP via DHCP but DHCP would know that the NIC with that MAC address always assign the same IP... This is possible on the Windows DHCP server side for sure.

Comment: Yes, I can; and I did. But I need whole thing to be dynamic as part of a DR solution: the VM will change IP address when moved to the DR network, and I would like it to automatically register itself in the DNS (otherwise I'll need to set up a whole bunch of Azure automation and scripting in order to manually modify static A records during the DR process).

Comment: This of course works automagically for Windows machines; I know it can work for Linux machines too, but I'm getting a bit confused at the lack of documentation (or at the abundance of flawed documentation, which is even worse) for a scenario where both DHCP and dynamic DNS registration are required and you don't have control of the DHCP service.